# Aligning points in WGS84 to centroid of features in projected CRS (EPSG:28992) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, alignment

I have a set of points in `WGS84` representing the rainfall over the Netherlands, as acquired by radar towers. These points represent the centroid of a pixel in WGS84 and they are separately by (roughly) 1km.

In the project I am working, I would like to use a projected CRS, in this case [EPSG:28992](https://epsg.io/28992) (official Dutch CRS). I created a 1km grid in `EPSG:28992` and I overlaid the points, after transforming them from WGS84 to `EPSG:28992`. You can see an image illustrating the problem below.

[image]

As expected, the centroid of the reprojected `WGS84` points does not coincide with the centroid of the pixels in `EPSG:28992`. Hence, I believe the task to do here is to align each of these points with the **closest centroid of the pixels** in `EPSG:28992`. However, I am not sure whether this reasoning is correct, because since there is this inclination of the points I might assign a red dot to the incorrect pixel.

Can you guide me on how to do this properly using QGIS?

**EDIT:** The purpose of aligning is because the rest of the analysis will be done using numpy arrays (matrices), and I think it is easier to prepare the data in a projected CRS, since then each cell of the array corresponds to each pixel of the CRS. The overlaid grid is just to illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: What is the purpose of 'aligning'.

Comment: I don't get why you created a grid.

Comment: nmtoken: The purpose of aligning is because the rest of the analysis will be done using numpy arrays (matrices), and I think it is easier to prepare the data in a projected CRS, since then each cell of the array corresponds to each pixel of the CRS. Erik: I created a grid just to illustrate what the problem is. I edited the question to reflect these.

Comment: Use the original data, create the grid, assign the values and at last you reproject the grid (not the points)

Comment: In addition to JGH comment, if you want to get the centroids of the grid, you can go to `Vector -> Geometry tools -> Centroids`

Comment: It might have to do with the definition of EPSG 28992. More information (in Dutch) can be found here: https://qgis.nl/2011/12/05/epsg28992-of-rijksdriehoekstelsel-verschuiving/